# Symfony Validator cannot see property values for Entitites loaded from Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-validator

I have an entity which is loaded from the database using Doctrine.

This entity has a [Custom Mapping Type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) for a property.

In some cases Doctrine will return the proxy for this entity, and when I pass this to Symfony Validator it incorrectly reports that the property is Blank.

I believe this is because the validator uses reflection to access the property directly (rather than via the getter). Because the getter is not used, the proxy is not prompted to load the value for property and so the Validator sees it as being blank.

**Is there a trick to ensure that Symfony Validator will not be tripped up validating a Proxy?**

---

*I don't want to configure the entity to always eagerly load. My current workaround is to check if the entity is an instance of `\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy` and then call `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Proxy::__load()` to ensure all properties are loaded.*

Comment: Have you tried the GetSetMethodNormalizer? See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#adding-normalizers-and-encoders

Comment: IIRC Symfony does not use reflection for accessing properties, it usually uses its PropertyPath component that looks for accessor methods or throws an exception

Comment: Thanks for this information @malarzm.  I have checked that the property definitely has a value prior to validating. When I do this validation passes because having called the getter to check for the value forces it to be loaded -- when not calling the getter myself, validation fails. So if the Validator is not using reflection then I will dig into the Symfony/Doctrine code to see how it is the property value is not there when the Validator requests it.